# Manage authorization with Azure API Management and Function App as back-end

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Currently I have been working in a project to implement few APIs hosted on Azure and make them publicly available via Azure API Management service. At the moment, the APIM service communicates with the Function App (API), and the Function App has  the authorization level as Function. So, anytime there is a request to the APIM service, this request is forwarded to the Function App, and the code is injected to the request be authorized. But, at the moment we are managing policies on XML files, and consequently the authorization code is hard coded on these files. So I was wondering if you have any suggestion in terms of managing these codes dynamically, without hard-coding them to these files, since the files are saved in Azure DevOps repos... At the moment, we have a pipeline set-up on Azure DevOps to manage policies changes, so anytime there is a change, it will upload the new policies files to a Storage Account, and then we deploy an ARM template to configure all the APIM service, with the new policies.

Any ideas how to manage those codes without hard-code them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and analysis about the different options, i end-up using the listSecrets function, from the Functions resource, in the ARM template. So, i store the result (function key) of the function's call in a variable, and then i use that variable to compose the function's URL and associate it on the back-end service on the API Management API policies. More info in relation with the listSecrets function in this [link](https://blog.mexia.com.au/list-of-access-keys-from-output-values-after-arm-template-deployment#functions).

Thank you Vitaliy for the help.

Answer (score 2):

See here on how to use named values in policies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-properties. They're created specifically to abstract some common parameters and/or secrets away from policy code.

In addition, you could check how Function App import works in APIM right now. After import you have:

1. An API for a Function App
2. An operation for a selected Function in Function App
3. A backend entity - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/azure-api-management-rest-api-backend-entity - that points to your function app and references named value with a key to a function
4. Named value that holds function key and is marked as a secret.

All that allows you to boil down policy code to call Function app to:

```
<set-backend-service id="my-function-app" />
```

Comment: I understand the idea of the first link, so i could map the function app auth key (master or function key) to a named value as secret, and then use it on the APIM policies. But, the problem is i am using Staging slots on the function apps. So consequently, if i deploy to the staging slot, and swap with production slot, then the production slot will have different auth keys, since the master and function keys will change. The second link, to use the APIM REST Api, i don't get the idea.

Comment: Second link merely allows you to abstract function app a bit more from policy. You could use host keys instead, those do not change with slot swap.

Comment: Vitaliy, that's not true. The host keys change when you swap slots, and i would say this is because each slot is running on a separate instance than the production slot. Consequently, each instance has different host keys. And when i swap staging slot with production slot, the product host keys change, because the staging instance becomes my production instance running.

Comment: I've just tested it and I do see that active slot host keys remain in place after swap. In sense that same host key continues to work after swap to invoke functions that were brought up from another slot.

Comment: Hi Vitaliy, i found the reason for why i was having a different behavior than you in relation with the swap of slots for the functions and getting (or not getting) the keys swapped. So apparently it all depends on the type of key storage mechanism that you are using on. According to this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Changes-to-Key-Management-in-Functions-V2) if you use the mechanism of file system to key storage, then on the swap slots, the host keys will change. If you use Blob mechanism, then the host keys do not change.